# Restricting 3rd party extensions for startup performance (actionEvents)

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code

I looked at my *Startup Performance* results and I saw that official and some other extensions has been restricted **actionEvents** which is not activated until some language type file is opened(onLanguaged)

```
| ritwickdey.LiveServer             | true  | 248     | 3    | 43    | *   | ritwickdey.LiveServer               |
| RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode         | true  | 5       | 2    | 41    | *   | RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode           |
| usernamehw.relative-line-height   | true  | 1       | 0    | 41    | *   | usernamehw.relative-line-height     |
```

But these 3rd party extensions are not restricted so it's affecting my startup performance.

Is there any way I can restrict them myself?

*example of restricted extension*

```
| vscode.emmet     | false | 51   | 10   | 431    | onLanguage:html    | vscode.emmet  |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the command "`Show Running Extensions`" you will see a list of the activated extensions in your VS Code instance. You will also see, to the right, how long each extension took to activate in ms.

- open command palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> Or `View => Command palette`.

[image]

- Right click on those you don't need and disactivate

[image]